# change ajax tabcontainer tabs height and width

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i coudn't find a way to change the tabcontainer's tab width and height.

i am able to get the active tab as below

```
var tab = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelAttributes1_TabContainer1');
var currentTabIndex = tab.control._activeTabIndex;
var currentTab = tab.control._tabs[currentTabIndex];
```

so what is the next thing?

```
$(currentTab).css('width',400);
$(currentTab).css('height',400);
```

is not working for me

Comment: why are you mixing js and jQ together? use one of them!

Comment: Please provide us a fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing jQuery and JS

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelAttributes1_TabContainer1").css({'width':400,'height':400});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wpQ2b/